# Paypal : Paypal doesn't accept payment in £

Tags: paypal, currency

In my application, while making payment through paypal in Pound, Paypal returns me an error that says -

```
The recipent does not accept payments denomination in POU. Please contact the seller and ask him to update his payment receiving preferences to accept this curency.
```

In my paypal account, there are two currency settings -

1. British Pound (Primary)  [GBP]
2. US Dollors [USD]

The paypal only accepts payment in US Dollors but not in Pound.
How do I resolve this problem. Any direction or hint will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're passing CURRENCYCODE or currency_code as POU or POUND. Use 'GBP' instead.